# Add index as dropdown menu in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting chart using below code:

```
fig = px.line(df, x='Time', y=['one','two'], color= df.index)
fig['layout']['xaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
fig.update_layout(legend_title="Price")
fig.show()
```

Dataframe i am working with like is below:

```
      Time   one    two
100   9:30   129    243
110  10:30   234    453
120  11:00   155    234
```

Want to add dropdown menu to select from index and show one row at a time in chart.
example if i select 110 from drop down it should only show chart for that row.
Is there any easy fix for it.
Thank you in adavance.

Comment: You've already received working solution, but would you care for a Plotly Dash approach as well?

Comment: @vestland yes please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution: 
**In order to set the proper options for the dropdown menu, it would be helpful to have a function that creates the list of options (shown below)**

```py
# Create proper buttons list
def makeButtonsList(idxs):
    buttons = []
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
        visibleArr = np.full((2*df.index.shape[0],), 
                             False, dtype=bool)       # 2x number of booleans since one/two vals are separate plots
        visibleArr[2*i] = True                        # Set two booleans next to each other (representing one & two) to true
        visibleArr[(2*i)+1] = True
        buttons.append(dict(label=str(idx),
                            method='update',
                            args=[{'visible': list(visibleArr)}]))    # 'Visible' arg determines which plots are shown 
                                                                      # depending on which dropdown is selected 
    return buttons
```

**Next create the traces for the data (with your sample data, I created a bar chart but you could easily modify this)**

```py
traces = []
for i in range(df.Time.shape[0]):
    rowData = df.iloc[i, :]
    time = rowData.Time
    one = rowData.one
    two = rowData.two
    traces.append(go.Bar(x=[time], y=[one], name='One'))
    traces.append(go.Bar(x=[time], y=[two], name='Two'))
```

where `df` is the dataframe you are working with.

**Finally put it all together and create the Plotly plot!**

```py
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# Create proper buttons list
def makeButtonsList(idxs):
    buttons = []
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
        visibleArr = np.full((2*df.index.shape[0],), 
                             False, dtype=bool)       # 2x number of booleans since one/two vals are separate plots
        visibleArr[2*i] = True                        # Set two booleans next to each other (representing one & two) to true
        visibleArr[(2*i)+1] = True
        buttons.append(dict(label=str(idx),
                            method='update',
                            args=[{'visible': list(visibleArr)}]))    # 'Visible' arg determines which plots are shown 
                                                                      # depending on which dropdown is selected 
    return buttons

# Create traces
traces = []
for i in range(df.Time.shape[0]):
    rowData = df.iloc[i, :]
    time = rowData.Time
    one = rowData.one
    two = rowData.two
    traces.append(go.Bar(x=[time], y=[one], name='One'))
    traces.append(go.Bar(x=[time], y=[two], name='Two'))

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure(data=traces)

# Add dropdown options
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=makeButtonsList(df.index),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.55,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.2,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)


# Add annotation for index selected
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="Index:", showarrow=False,
        x=0, y=1.15, yref="paper", align="left")
    ],
    xaxis_title = 'Time',
    yaxis_title = 'Value',
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Here is a sample plot:
[image: Plot1]

**BONUS:**
If you think this method is tedious, and a slider bar would do the job just fine, Plotly supports animation of bar charts. Here is the following code you could use:

```py
fig = px.bar(df, x='Time', y=['one','two'], animation_frame=df.index)
fig.update_layout(title='Data', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Here is the resulting plot:
[image: Plot2]

Comment: it throws me an error on this line "for i in range(df2.Time.shape[0]):" as "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Time'". My time column is set as 12 hour with AM/PM . Can you please help me fix this issue

Comment: @Zac It seems that either you don’t have a `df2` variable (this it is of type `None`) or the the `df2` data frame variable has no column `Time`

Comment: I have everything in place its just that TIme column is as object and is write as 10:20 PM format. [dataframe i have](https://imgur.com/a/g6OK2Xa). please help me get it fix .

Comment: @Zac Since you just need to loop through all the rows in the dataframe `df`, you should be able to modify the for loop to `for i in range(df.shape[0]):`

Comment: its working but it only shows one data at a time i have same multiple index number with different time frame please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912938/multiple-index-dropdown-option-plotly) i have explained it better in this.